# Firefox 24.0 onclick not firing on the right target

Tags: javascript, firefox, html, svg, onclick

I've been having some major issues with Firefox lately. My code runs smooth in Chrome, but Firefox seems to be having some trouble figuring out what I'm clicking on. Have you guys heard of this? I've basically got a bunch of SVG's within divs. The divs have an onclick event to call a function, which does fire, but on the wrong div. So I'm clicking a div to the right and a div to the left receives the click.

here is the javascript

http://pastebin.com/wbYnqT4B

and here is the HTML

http://pastebin.com/aXMyYtS8

It generates these elements and positions them throughout the page, and when clicked, should have a box appear containing information about the element. But other elements seem to be claiming to be the events target, despite me clicking several hundreds of pixels away from them.

```
<div id="6-084" class="room" fullname="John Smith" phonenum="None" pcname="Unknown" wallplatenum="Unknown" onclick="displayInfo(event)" style="height: 72px; width: 96px; position: absolute; left: 753px; top: 236px; opacity: 1;">
    <svg id="6-084-svg" style="-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;" class="room">
        <g id="6-084-svg-g">
            <path style="fill:none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 2;" d="M 95,1 L 95,51 Q 80,51 80,66 L 95,66 L 95,71 L 1,71 L 1,1 Z "></path>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <div id="6-084 divP" style="position: absolute; z-index: 2; top: 20.5px; left: 34px;">
        <p id="6-084 P" style="text-align:center;">Name</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You'll see exactly what I'm talking about when you click the SVG for the one labeled "54" and it fires on the SVG for "57". It also fires just fine if you click the p tag containing the "54". So I'm guessing this has something to do with SVGs.

Any ideas?

(also, I know everything is unaligned, and I apologize for that. I just rewrote how it creates the path tags so I wouldn't need to worry about div rotation when placing them, and now everything is misplaced.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
svg.setAttribute("width", "100%");
svg.setAttribute("height", "100%");
```

after every one of these lines

```
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
```

And that seems to fix it. At the moment you're relying on a webkit bug for your code to work.

Comment: How strange... I just figured the SVG automatically had those as the defaults, seeing as that is how it seems to work in Chrome. Thanks so much!

Comment: You aren't alone there, however the [SVG specification says different](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewportSpace). Note that all the bullet points are true so that means that leaving width unset doesn't do what you think it ought to.